# Update 2 values in one temporary table T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update

I would like your help for a query. I have a temporary table with value(float), attribute(nvarchar) and system(int). I need to update the values depending the attribute, but using the system. So...

```
UPDATE #inventory (value, attribute)
SET (value, attribute) = (SELECT SUM(value), 'Actual'
                        FROM ReportValue v, ReportValueType t, ReportProducts ti
                        WHERE v.type_id = t.id
                        AND v.voyage_id = ti.id
                        AND t.value_code = 'total'
                        AND t.category_code = 'cold'
                        AND ti.end_time BETWEEN @start AND @end)
UPDATE #inventory (value, attribute)
SET (value, attribute) = (SELECT SUM(value), 'Actual'
                        FROM ReportValue v, ReportType t, Reportprod ti
                        WHERE v.type_id = t.id
                        AND v.voyage_id = ti.id
                        AND t.field_name = 'Total'
                        AND t.slot_type = 'COLD'
                        AND t.xml_id = -2000
                        AND ti.end_time BETWEEN @start AND @end)
else (value, attribute)
end
```

This is the wrong form. How can I get it working?
Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: what is wrong about it and what is the correct form? could you give an example?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, and your UPDATE syntax is 100% wrong for any DBMS I've ever seen. Until you clarify your question to make it clear what you're trying to do, however, it's pretty difficult to show you how to do it properly. Can you edit your question text and clearly state what you're trying to accomplish? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it semms you are trying too get your head around update syntax...  (that is compliant):

```
UPDATE tblNameCanBeTempTable
SET Column1 = S.Value1, Column2 = S.Value2, etc
FROM (anyValidSelectTableStatement) S
    WHERE tblNameCanBeTempTable.KeyValue =  S.keyValue
```

So the route is make your select statment, check it produces the values you want, then tack the update ont the beginning and the row matching WHERE on the end

You Can do things like

`Col1 = CASE WHEN X=1 THEN S.Value1 ELSE Col1 END`

for each row.